# Duda wordpress y enlaces amigables

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, reescritura-url

Llevo un par de dias trabajando en una web y quiero que todas las urls sean amigables, es decir, que ninguna url sea asi `subcategoria/?type=ejemplo1`, el problema es que tambien quiero todos los tipos de datos custom y no se me ocurre otra manera de filtrar los datos que pasar los datos por `GET` y hacer consultas.

Estaria eternamente agradecido si alguien puede decirme como cambiar la url para que esto `miweb.com/subcategoria/?type=ejemplo1` se ve asi `miweb.com/subcategoria/ejemplo1`.

He intentado cambiarlo con el `.htaccess` de mil formas pero no hay manera.

Comment: Hola Fran, bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Si no recuerdo mal, también hay que cambiar ciertas configuraciones de WordPress: edita tu pregunta añadiendo qué fue lo último que intentaste con `.htaccess` y qué error obtenías para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: he probado esto RewriteRule ^subcategoria/(.*)/(.*)/$ archive-subcategoria.php?type=$1&pagina=$2
 RewriteRule ^subcategoria/(.*)/$ archive-subcategoria.php?type=$1, y con esto (# RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=(.*)&pagina=(.*)$
 # RewriteRule ^.*$ subcategoria/%1/page/%2 [L,R=301]) ponia la url como queria pero no me eliminaba el ?type=ejemplo y me llevaba al 404

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta para añadirlo y que quede más claro.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que ir a ajustes de wordpress y luego a enlaces permanentes, allí tienes varias opciones que te dejan mostrar tus urls como más te guste. te dejo un link de ayuda: (http://www.pasionseo.com/como-crear-url-amigables-en-wordpress/)

Si lo entiendo bien creo que esto podría resolver lo que quieres hacer: (http://blog.ikhuerta.com/seo-on-page-estructura-web-en-wordpress-categorias-urls-y-links)

Comment: te expongo mejor mi problema. estoy trabajando en una web en la que estoy creando tipos de datos custom, con sus respectivas categorias, tambien objetos custom.
Tengo que filtrar los datos por categorias y paginarlos, lo que se me habia ocurrido es hacer una consulta sql y calcular un limit para hacer otra consulta e ir moviendome con limit entre las "paginas", el problema seria simplemente que no quiero que en la url aparezca:
(miweb.com?type=categoria&pagina=2) sino (miweb.com/subcategoria/categoria/page/2), he estado probando con el htaccess y no hay manera.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta  @Fran a ver si te ayudo más!

Answer (score 0):

Para poner enlaces amigables en Wordpress no hace falta tocar el .htacces.
Lo que debes hacer es:

1. Accede con tu usuario y contraseña
2. En el menú de la derecha haz clic en "ajustes" y luego en "enlaces permanentes"
3. Selecciona la opción que más se adapte a tus necesidades

Fíjate en la última opción que te permite adaptarlo usando comodines, un ejemplo sería:

/subcategoria/%tipoCategoria%/

Esto serviría para hacer url amigables, lo de la paginación es otra historia. Igual te sirve este enlace https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Comment: Pero si tu plataforma no permite a WordPress actualizar el .htaccess de nada sirve picar mil veces en los enlaces permanentes, estos dependen de una correcta configuración en .htaccess o en la configuración de Apache.